# How do I read a JNDI property from a Client GWT app

Tags: java, gwt, jndi

On Server side, there is a JNDI resource, that I need to read from a Client GWT App.
I know, that I can make a GWT RPC call to get the JNDI resource dynamically, but the JNDI resource is a static URL, that will not change, once the page is loaded. So - my idea was to load the JNDI resource when loading the page. 
I found an outdated description about how this could be done - in 2011

  https://webtide.com/gwt-and-jndi/

However, I would like to know, whether this would be possible for a more current version of GWT (I am using GWT 2.7.0)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Pass JNDI parameters and some other configuration values to the GWT application.

The trick is to generate the GWT hostpage dynamically (with JSP in my case).

Each inital call to my GWT application goes to a front controller (a Servlet) for authorizition purposes and some other intitialization stuff.

Then I get all the JNDI parameters and other values, put them into the request context and call the hostpage JSP.

In my JSP page I define a JavaScript hash and initialize it with the parameters.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var my_params = {
  jndiParam1: '<%= request.getAttribute("jndiParam1") %>',
  exampleUrl: '<%= request.getAttribute("exampleUrl") %>',
  jndiParam2: '<%= request.getAttribute("jndiParam2") %>'
};
</script>
```

And inside my GWT application I have a class `HostPageParameter` which uses a `com.google.gwt.i18n.client.Dictionary` to access the JavaScript hash `my_params`.

```
public class HostPageParameter {
  private static final String DICTNAME = "my_params";
  private static HostPageParameter instance = null;

  public static HostPageParameter getInstance() {
    if(instance == null) {
      instance = new HostPageParameter();
    }
    return instance;
  }

  private Dictionary myParams;

  private HostPageParameter() {
    try {
      myParams = Dictionary.getDictionary(DICTNAME);
    } catch(MissingResourceException e) {
      // If not defined
      myParams = null;
    }
  }

  public String getParameter(String paramName) {
    return getParameter(paramName, null);
  }

  public String getParameter(String paramName, String defaultValue) {
    String paramValue = null;

    if(myParams != null && paramName != null) {
      try {
        paramValue = myParams.get(paramName);
      } catch (MissingResourceException e) {
        // If not defined
        paramValue = defaultValue;
      }
    }
    return paramValue;
  }
}
```

And to read the values you simply can use:

```
// Without a default value, If not defined, null is returned.
final String jndiParam1 = HostPageParameter.getInstance().getParameter("jndiParam1");

// With default value.
final String exampleUrl = HostPageParameter.getInstance().getParameter("exampleUrl", 
    "http://example.com");
```